# Multiple Authorizers for single AWS API Endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, authorization, aws-api-gateway

I have an AWS API endpoint defined as:

```
MyApi:
Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
Properties:
  Name: MyApi
  StageName: dev
```

Then I have one endpoint defined as:

```
SampleEvent:
  Type: Api
  Properties:
    RestApiId: !Ref MyApi
    Path: /api/sample
    Method: POST
```

I need to expose this API to 2 different stakeholders. These are the requirements:

- Stakeholder1 would only support lambda authorization.
- Stakeholder2 would only support AWS_IAM authorization.

So, I need to expose a same endpoint but need to make it support 2 different authorization mechanisms. What are the options?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to configure multiple authorizers for a single API.
I think you can use a separate API with context path /vendor1 and /vendor2, then you can apply different AuthZ for each of them. Hope it helps.